# How to add role to user using ws in WSO2 AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to add a role to a user using admin services in wso2 am instead of ui but i can't find the right service. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

UserAdmin is the service that is used by Carbon UI as mentioned by Abimaran. But if you want to call from an external application, the recommended service is `RemoteUserStoreManagerService`

```
https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `https://localhost:8243/services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint`. There is an operation called `addRole`